# Attach work item to Azure DevOps Pull Request

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am working on an approach to attach a work item to a Pull Request via an API in Azure DevOps.

I have attempted the following method, but it has not successfully tagged the work item.

```
$requestUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/12345?api-version=4.1"
$prapi1 = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repo/pullRequests/12345"

$json = @"
[ {
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/relations/-",
  "value": {
    "rel": "ArtifactLink",
    "url": "$pr",
    "attributes": { "name": "pull request" }
  }
} ]
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestUri -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Method Patch -Body $json
```

However, when using the specified API, I encounter an error instructing me to:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid Resource Link Target:
> 'https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/git/repositories/repo/pullRequests/12345'.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemResourceLinkException,
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server","typeKey":"WorkItemResourceLinkException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3200}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your script sample, the cause of the issue is that the pr url is not correct.

The correct format: `vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/{projectId}/{repositoryId}/{pullRequestId}`

You can get the Pull Request URL in the Rest API: [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#gitpullrequest)

It will show the **artifactId** in the response.

For example:

[image]

Here is the PowerShell sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$PullRequest="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{projectname}/_apis/git/repositories/{reponame}/pullrequests/{PullRequestID}?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PullRequest -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Method Get

$url= $response.artifactId
echo $url

$requestUri = " https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemid}?api-version=7.1-preview.3"

$json = @"
[ {
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/relations/-",
  "value": {
    "rel": "ArtifactLink",
    "url": "$url",
    "attributes": { "name": "pull request" }
  }
} ]
"@


$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $requestUri -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Method Patch -Body $json
```

Comment: Awesome.. his worked.. Thanks for the Response..